# How to change Visio 2010 Shape Label inside the shape sheet

Tags: ms-office, visio

I am wondering if there is a way to change the text displayed below a shape using a value entered into the user defined shape data. Basically something like:

shape.TextBelowShapeImage = Prop.Name

It would be nice if this shape property were somewhere in the shape sheet.

Thank you for any help.

Wayne E. Pfeffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this by using **Fields**. The key is to use the **AddCustomFieldU** method on the shapes **Characters** object.

Assume you have a shape with a property having a *label* of "FOO" with value "BAR". (The property is stored in a named row - in this case "Prop.Row_1" which is only visible in the ShapeSheet for the shape.

```
Dim vsoCharacters2 As Visio.Characters
Set vsoCharacters2 = myshape.Characters
vsoCharacters2.Begin = 0
vsoCharacters2.End = 0
vsoCharacters2.AddCustomFieldU "Prop.Row_1", visFmtNumGenNoUnits
```

After this code is run, the text of the shape will appear as "BAR"